# How to discard observable that has not been returned

Tags: angular, rxjs

The user clicks the first page and then the second page. Due to the different return time of the request, a bug is caused, resulting in the user finally seeing the data on the first page.

I want to discard the incomplete `observable`. Is there a corresponding `Operator`?

The correct result of the following example should only output 2

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

let time = null;

const o = new Observable((s) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    s.next();
  }, time);
}).pipe(); // <- I think I should add something

function render (pageNumber) {
  o.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(`Render page ${pageNumber}`);
  });
}
// The user wants to see the first page
time = 2000;
render(1);

// After 1ms...
// The user wants to see the second page
time = 1;
render(2);

// Due to the different return time of the request:
// 1. the first page returns in 2 seconds
// 2. the econd page returns in 1ms
// As a result, the second page is rendered first, and then the first page is rendered. The user finally sees the first page.This is wrong and the user should see the second page.
```

Comment: If you don't subscribe then no `setTimeout()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose timer is something that you assign randomly to simulate api request time. The following pattern is better, when next page request comes in, with `switchMap` it'll cancel the previous one

```
render
  .pipe(switchMap((obj: any) => timer(obj.time).pipe(mapTo(obj.page))))
  .subscribe(console.log);

render.next({ time: 2000, page: 1 });
//request for page 2 immediately 
render.next({ time: 1, page: 2 });
//request for page 3 after 3 second
setTimeout(() => render.next({ time: 1000, page: 3 }), 3000);
```

In above example you will only see page 2 and 3 print to console.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g5e5zf?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit weird. If you set a async action (your timeOut) inside your Observable creation and call next with inside it, your observable will emit based on how long the async action takes. I think you're looking for switchMap in this case.

Example (not tested):

```js
// Create observable
const _a$ = new Subject();
const a$ = _a$.pipe(

    // User input so maybe wait a bit first for user to be done clicking
    debounceTime(100),

    // Then switchMap to cancel previous and switch to the new result you want
    switchMap(async x => {

        // Do some async page rendering
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 2000));

    })
);


a$.subscribe();

// The user wants to see the first page
_a$.next(1);

// The user wants to see the second page
_a$.next(2);
```